# Vim - top of screen follows cursor

Tags: vim

In insert mode, whenever I move the cursor up or down, the top of the display window immediately follows the cursor, not letting me see any lines above. Is there any commands to fix this?

Comment: Which keys are you pressing to move the cursor up and down?

Comment: put the code that you try..

Comment: Do you have `scrolloff` in your vimrc?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, I don't see any problem there. I mean as you write more, it's part of the usability of Vim, you wont see lines above. On the either hand, if you can see only the line where you are in , there is a problem. It this happen using other kind of editors like VI, Cat, or gedit ?